# Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "и правда"?

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "и правда"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не выделяется. Слово "правда" может выделяться запятыми, если это вводное слово.
Пример: "Он, правда, был тогда совсем маленьким"